# Usar room por injection en una clase con hilt que no es AppCompatActivity()

Tags: android, kotlin, room, hilt

Estoy iniciando con hilt, mi idea es hacer una función independiente en una clase aparte que no es fragmento ni `AppCompatActivity`, este código en *mainactivity* funciona pero en una clase aparte no:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LogReg {

    @Inject
    lateinit var logTblDao: LogTBLDao

    fun saveLog(data1: String, data2: String){
        GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            logTblDao.insertLogTbl(
                LogTBL(
                    null,
                    GetDateTime().getDateTime(),
                    data1,
                    data2
                )
            )
            //Para mantener no mas de 500 registros en la tabla
            logTblDao.updateLOG()
        }
    }
}
```

El error es:

```
[Hilt] @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity, (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.
```

Me queda claro que no viene de una actividad, la pregunta es, ¿es posible usar esta función simple como la estoy pensando?

Answer (score 0):

Estas usando la anotación [`@AndroidEntryPoint`](https://dagger.dev/hilt/android-entry-point.html), esto es lo que indica:

> [@AndroidEntryPoint](https://dagger.dev/hilt/android-entry-point.html) Una vez que haya habilitado la inyección de
> miembros en su aplicación, puede comenzar a habilitar la inyección de
> miembros en sus otras clases de Android usando la anotación
> @AndroidEntryPoint. Puede utilizar @AndroidEntryPoint en los
> siguientes tipos:
>
> - Activity
> - Fragment
> - View
> - Service
> - BroadcastReceiver

Por lo que el error :

> [Hilt] @AndroidEntryPoint base class must extend ComponentActivity,
> (support) Fragment, View, Service, or BroadcastReceiver.

Indica que en tu caso tratas de habilitar inyección de dependencias en la clase `LogReg`, pero esta no extiende de alguna de las clases que indica la anotación.

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class LogReg {
```

En este caso considera mejor modificar tu clase `LogReg` para que le puedas enviar las dependencias como parámetros del constructor

```
class LogReg(private val logTblDao: LogTBLDao) {

    fun saveLog(data1: String, data2: String) {
    ...
    ...
```